# real analysis (open or closed set)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Is $[-12,7)\cup \{9,10\}$ a open or closed set? Can anyone give me an answer with explanation? I've searched many notes and websites. I'm so confused with many answers.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  It's neither

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the usual topology on $\mathbb R$, a set could be open, closed, both (e.g., empty set and $\mathbb R$), or neither.

Yours is neither.

It's not closed, because it doesn't contain limit point $7$.

It's not open, because it doesn't contain a neighborhood of $9$ or $10$.

Comment: Thank you very much.